# Which language will be generated by the following grammar?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar, formal-systems, formal-grammar

So i have

$$ G = (V,\sum, S, P) $$

while $$ V = {S, A, B} $$

$$ \sum = {a,b,c}$$

and for P:
$$ P:= \begin{cases} 
      S \rightarrow & cA\ | \ bB,  \\
      A \rightarrow & c, \\
      B \rightarrow & aB\ | \ b \\ 
   \end{cases}
\
$$

So with that definition, i need know to find the derivatives of:

$$ cc $$ and
$$ baaaab $$

How does that actually work? My approach would be for cc:

cc => cA and since A => c, we have for cc => cA.

but i am totally unsure, so any tips or ways on how to solve that kind of problem properly for both cases would be very awesome!

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: You can't derive the string $cc$ from your productions. You can only derive $ca$ and the rest of the strings will be of the form $ba^\ast b.$ My guess for the language would be $\{ca\} \cup \mathcal L(ba^\ast b).$

Comment: HEy @Rodrigo! thanks for your input! I actually made a mistake, $ A \rightarrow c $, so i think it should be now easier?

Comment: Well, I would say the difficult is the same. As for my guess, it would become $\{cc\} \cup \mathcal L(ba^\ast b).$